# io.jsonwebtoken decode JWT claims before validating the signature

Tags: jwt, jjwt

Assuming I have multiple clients, I'm expecting from my "clientA" to provide a JWT token created with it's **privateKeyClientA**, like

```
String jwtToken = Jwts.builder()
        .claims()
        .issuer("ClientA")
        .expiration(expirationDate)
        .and()
        .signWith(privateKeyClientA)
        .compact() ;
```

to decode the claims, I can use

```
claims = Jwts.parser()
         .verifyWith(publicKeyClientA)  
         .build()
         .parseClaimsJws(jwtToken)
         .getBody();
```

But, how do you identify "**clientA**", so, **publicKeyClientA** before validating the JWT's signature in an "elegant way"?

p.s. I must use "JJWT :: API" (io.jsonwebtoken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

- use the key id in the header to identify the correct key.
- parse the JWT body and extract the issuer field.

If there is no `io.jsonwebtoken` support for parsing before validating, try another library.

Doing this yourself can be like so:

- parse `b` from "Bearer a.b.c"
- base64 decode (url safe)

  - note: some libs also use compression for b
- parse the resulting JSON document

  - preferably using pull parser, issuer is probably the first field
  - extract issuer field value

For header just parse `a` instead.